Почему dp не работает на andorid TV так как ожидается?
В Android TV я с использую Jetpack Compose, где размер Card выглядит по-разному на телевизорах с разрешением 720p (эмулятор) и 1080p (эмулятор).
720:

1080:

Card code:
...
Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(412.dp)
                .height(200.dp),
            border = CardDefaults.border(border = Border.None),
            colors = CardDefaults.colors(
                containerColor = ColorTokens.grey_40,
                contentColor = ColorTokens.white,
                focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
                focusedContentColor = Color.Black,
                pressedContainerColor = Color.Gray,
                pressedContentColor = Color.LightGray
            ),
            shape = CardDefaults.shape (shape = RoundedCornerShape(CornerRadiusTokens.radius_300.withDPIOffset(LocalContext.current))),
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        )
...

Я ожидал бы, что карточки будут выглядеть одинаково на обоих экранах, так как используется dp. Что я упускаю из виду?

А почему вы думаете что не работает? Можно посчитать размер dip в коде в пикселях и измерить его на снимке и сравнить.

Что вы подразумеваете под "одинаково"? dp - это, по сути, физическая величина, ваши карточки должны быть одинаковыми, если их мерять линейкой на экране, но в эмуляторах экран может масштабироваться.

@Style-7 добавил ответ

@woesss добавил ответ

Упускаете что 720р и 1080р как правило имеют разные размеры в dp. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27979314/5479247

@EugeneKrivenja да, я так понимаю это зависит от density. Но я добавил ответ, который вроде как учитавает этот фактор

Проблема в том, что наш дизайн был сделан для экрана с разрешением 1080p, и все значения элементов интерфейса указаны в пикселях (px), а не в dp. Это значит, что если попытаться использовать, скажем, 200px на разных экранах, то, очевидно, будет выглядеть по-разному.
Поэтому, чтобы поддерживать экраны 1080p и 720p, необходимо корректировать размеры с 1080 до 720 экранов.
Вот функция:
inline val Int.extToDp: Dp
    @Composable get() = with(LocalDensity.current) { this@extToDp.toDp() }

val Int.pxToDpWithOffset: Dp
    @Composable get() {
        val screenDensity: Float = LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi.toFloat()

        val factor: Float = when {
            screenDensity <= DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV -> {
                (screenDensity / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH)
            }

            else /* DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH */ -> {
                1f
            }
        }

        val adjustedDp: Int = (this * factor).roundToInt()
        return adjustedDp.extToDp
    }

Использование:
...
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(412.pxToDpWithOffset)
                .height(200.pxToDpWithOffset)
...

Дайте знать если, что то пропустил:)
